# Finding all primes $p$ such that $5p + 1$ is a perfect square.

Tags: number-theory

Finding all primes $p$ such that $5p + 1$ is a perfect square. I'm aware a perfect square is a natural number of the form $n^2$ but have no idea as to how to go about this.

Answer (score 7):

$$ n^2 - 1 = (n+1)(n-1) = 5 p $$

Answer (score 1):

More generally,
to find all solutions to
$pq+1=\square$
where $p$ and $q$ are prime:

$pq = n^2-1
=(n+1)(n-1)$.

If $n=2$,
$pq = 3$
which can not be.

If $n > 2$ then
either
$n+1 = p, n-1 = q$
or
$n-1 = p, n+1 = q$.

In the first case,
$n = p-1 = q+1$
so $p = q+2,
n = q+1$.

Therefore $p$ and $q$ must be a
twin prime pair.

Comment: Who said anything about a $q$?

Comment: q=5 for this problem.

Comment: There is no $q$. Please pay attention to the question.

Comment: This problem is the case where $q=5$ is fixed. Please pay attention to my answer.

Comment: If HKT is the downvoter on this, that takes massive cajones.